How can I implement real-time notifications in a React.js application using WebSockets?
I'm working on a React.js application where I need to implement real-time notifications. The goal is to push updates (like new messages, alerts, or any event) to the user's screen as soon as they occur, without requiring the user to refresh the page.
I've researched WebSockets and understand that they can be used to maintain a persistent connection between the client and server, allowing the server to send updates to the client in real time.
I have a basic setup with a React frontend and a Node.js/Express backend. I'm familiar with using libraries like socket.io for WebSockets in Node.js, but I'm unsure how to efficiently integrate this with my React components to handle real-time notifications.
I've also looked into useEffect hooks in React for handling side effects like WebSocket connections, but I'm concerned about managing the connection lifecycle (open, close, reconnect) properly and avoiding memory leaks.
